# How to push data from an Oracle table to a SQL Server table?

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008

How best to periodically push data from a table in Oracle 10.2.0.4 to a table in SQL Server 2008 SP2?  The two tables are exactly alike, other than the necessary differences in datatypes.

I'm hoping to find a way that does not involve purchasing 3rd party software.

It needs to be automated and periodic.  The SQL Server is Standard edition.

Comment: SSIS package? linked servers? jobs? stored procedures? here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlperf/archive/2009/08/14/using-ssis-to-get-data-out-of-oracle-a-big-surprise.aspx

Comment: Could even go low tech and use a scheduled task + powershell, or Cygwin + a bash script.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is flat file out of oracle, and then flat file into SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you create an SSIS task for this purpose. Then you can use SQL Agent to schedule this task.

Comment: This sounds reasonable.  As usual, I'm asking the question weeks before I'll actually be doing the task, so it will be awhile before I can verify this. Perhaps Oracle has a better tool, as doubtful as that is.  More likely, the specific version or edition of SQL Server or Oracle will lack what I need.  We'll see.